# Returning Unique rows from Left Outer Join

Tags: sql, outer-join

I am trying to build a query which will give me unique rows. Details:-

```
Table 1 (F1, F2 are the columns)
F1  F2
1   A1
2   A2
3   A3
4   A4

Table 2 (F3,F4 are the columns)
F3  F4
1   B1
1   B11
2   B2
2   B22
```

My Query (Incorrect)
select rrn(A), F1,F2,F3,F4 from rush2hem1.T1 A left outer join rush2hem1.T2 B on A.F1=B.F3

This gives me below output which is not what I am looking for:-

```
RRN F1  F2  F3  F4
1   1   A1 1    B1 
1   1   A1 1    B11 
2   2   A2 2    B2 
2   2   A2 2    B22 
3   3   A3 (null)   (null)
4   4   A4 (null)   (null)
```

Expected output that I am building query for is:-

```
RRN F1  F2  F3  F4
1   1   A1 1    B1 
2   2   A2 2    B2 
3   3   A3 (null)   (null)
4   4   A4 (null)   (null)
```

Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Comment: among the two rows such as `A1...B1` and `A1...B11`, why do you prefer the former?

Answer (score 2):

This problem could be solved differently in different RDBMS. In any case, you have to specify which one record from `Table2` do you want to get (by `order by` clause)

If your database have window function `row_number()`, you can use it like this:

```
select
    F1, F2, F3, F4
from (
    select
        T1.F1, T1.F2, T2.F3, T2.F4,
        -- order by specifying which row you would get from Table2
        row_number() over(partition by T1.F1 order by T2.F4) as rn
    from Table1 as T1
        left outer join Table2 as T2 on T2.F3 = T1.F1
) as cte  
where rn = 1;
```

In SQL Server, you can use `outer apply`:

```
select
    T1.F1, T1.F2, T2.F3, T2.F4
from Table1 as T1
    outer apply (
        select top 1 T2.F3, T2.F4
        from Table2 as T2
        where T2.F3 = T1.F1
        order by T2.F3 asc   -- This is important line
    ) as T2;
```

In PostgreSQL, you can use `distinct on` syntax:

```
select distinct on (T1.F1)
    T1.F1, T1.F2, T2.F3, T2.F4
from Table1 as T1
    left outer join Table2 as T2 on T2.F3 = T1.F1
order by T1.F1, T2.F4; -- sort by F4 is important
```

- [**SQL Server sqlfiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/75de3/10)
- [**PostgreSQL sqlfiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/75de3/2)

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, It's a SQL server version.

```
select rrn(A), F1,F2,F3,F4
from
(
 select rrn(A), F1,F2,F3,F4,row_number() over(partition by RRN order by RRN) as rn
from rush2hem1.T1 A left outer join rush2hem1.T2 B 
on A.F1=B.F3
) as dt
where dt.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the result with `OUTER APPLY`

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    Table1 a
OUTER APPLY 
    (SELECT 
        TOP 1 * 
    FROM 
        Table2 b 
    WHERE a.F1=b.F3)c
```